# Strange behavior when using where clause in join with pagination

Tags: php, laravel-4, pagination

I have the following code:

```
$products = DB::table('products AS p')
                ->select('p.*', 'pi.image', 'b.name AS brand')
                ->leftJoin('products_images AS pi', function($join)
                {
                    $join->on('p.id', '=', 'pi.id_product')
                        ->where('pi.primary', '=', 2);
                })
                ->leftJoin('brands AS b', 'p.id_brand', '=', 'b.id')
                ->where('p.is_active', 1)
                ->where('id_category', 31)
                ->orderBy('p.name')
                ->get();
```

It works perfectly, but when I replace get() with paginate()

```
$products = DB::table('products AS p')
                ->select('p.*', 'pi.image', 'b.name AS brand')
                ->leftJoin('products_images AS pi', function($join)
                {
                    $join->on('p.id', '=', 'pi.id_product')
                        ->where('pi.primary', '=', 2);
                })
                ->leftJoin('brands AS b', 'p.id_brand', '=', 'b.id')
                ->where('p.is_active', 1)
                ->where('id_category', 31)
                ->orderBy('p.name')
                ->paginate(15);
```

It generates a query incorrectly (all 'where' conditions is mixed):

```
select `p`.*, `pi`.`image`, `b`.`name` as `brand` from `products` as `p` 
left join `products_images` as `pi` on `p`.`id` = `pi`.`id_product` and `pi`.`primary` = '2'
left join `brands` as `b` on `p`.`id_brand` = `b`.`id` 

where `p`.`is_active` = '2' and `id_category` = '1' 

order by `p`.`name` asc limit 15 offset 0
```

When I remove the 'where' clause in the anonymous function, all works fine.
Is it a bug in Laravel? or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried moving the ->where('pi.primary', '=', 2) out of the join closure and into the main query?

Comment: I doubt this would fix it, but in your second where clause wouldn't you need to specify the table which `id_category` belongs to? For example `p.id_category` - hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Laravelian Yes, if I do that, everything works well. But, it's not the same. I get the behavior is similar to inner join in your case.

Comment: @haakym Thanks. it's my mistake , but the fix does not solve the problem.

Comment: workaround: ...->leftJoin('products_images AS pi', 'p.id', '=', DB::raw('pi.id_product AND `pi`.`primary` = 2' ))